# Cpanel XML API installssl error

Tags: cpanel

```
<error>[an error occurred while processing this directive]</error>[2014-04-29 15:56:53 -0500] warn [xml-api] The system could not parse the certificate because o
f an error: A critical error occurred while parsing the ASN.1 data: Cpanel::CPAN::Encoding::BER: corrupt data? data appears truncated
at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SSL/Utils.pm line 724
at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SSLInfo.pm line 72
```

This is my call:

```
my $status = make_request($auth, "installssl?user=$user&domain=$domain&cert=@cert&key=@key&ip=$dedicated_ip");

sub make_request {
  my $auth = shift;
  my $params = shift;
  my $url = "https://127.0.0.1:2087/xml-api/" . $params;
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
  my $request = HTTP::Request->new( POST => $url );
  $request->header( Authorization => $auth );
  my $response = $ua->request($request);
  my $data = $response->content;
  my $xml = XML::Simple->new;
  $data = $xml->XMLin($data);
  if ( $data->{'status'} ) {
    return $data;
  } else {
    print "[!] Cpanel API returned an error: " . $data->{'statusmsg'} . "\n";
    exit;
  }
}
```

Statusmsg: [!] Cpanel API returned an error: The certificate appears to be invalid.

Comment: The SSL is self signed. Additionally it works installing with the SSL and Private Key via WHM.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by the XML-API support of InstallSSL being deprecated. I have resolved this by using API2 through XML-API:

```
sub make_api2_request {
    my $auth     = shift;
    my $user     = shift;
    my $domain   = shift;
    my $cert     = shift;
    my $key      = shift;
    my $bundle   = shift;
    my $url      = "https://127.0.0.1:2087/xml-api/cpanel";
    my $ua       = LWP::UserAgent->new();
    my $response = $ua->request(
        POST $url,
        Authorization => $auth,
        Content_Type  => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Content       => [
            'crt'                      => $cert,
            'domain'                   => $domain,
            'key'                      => $key,
            'cpanel_xmlapi_user'       => $user,
            'cpanel_xmlapi_module'     => 'SSL',
            'cpanel_xmlapi_func'       => 'installssl',
            'cpanel_xmlapi_apiversion' => 2,
        ],
    );
    my $data = $response->content;
    $data = XMLin($data);
    if ( $data->{'error'} ) {
        $data->{'error'} =~ s/[^[:ascii:]]+//g;
        print "[!] " . $data->{'error'} . "\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're missing some PERL dependencies. Run through this list to start, once you're done, go into WHM's SSL Storage Manager, delete any unused self-signed certs, regenerate (or run /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/gencrt from the CLI) and then see if any errors were thrown during the cert generation process. Good luck!

```
/scripts/perlinstaller Config::Crontab
/scripts/perlinstaller Date::Simple
/scripts/perlinstaller Digest::MD5
/scripts/perlinstaller HTTP::Request::Common
/scripts/perlinstaller IO::Handle
/scripts/perlinstaller IPC::Open3
/scripts/perlinstaller JSON::Syck
/scripts/perlinstaller LWP::UserAgent
/scripts/perlinstaller Mozilla::CA
/scripts/perlinstaller Template
/scripts/perlinstaller XML::Simple
/scripts/perlinstaller YAML::Syck
```